# Can two asp.net core web application coexists inside a same solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to have two asp.net core web application in a way that one app acts as mvc and other acts as a web api.

I tried doing so, I can compile it and run it but I cannot get data from api controller.

Here is an example

[image]

Comment: Where is the calling code for API?

Comment: Sure, you can have multiple web apps in one solution. You'll need to make sure to run all the projects you need in order for your app to function, instead of just launching a single one. Did you properly set your solution so that multiple apps launch when you start a debugging session?

Comment: You are right, let me rephrase my question. Can they run side by side under the same localhost/domain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938163/separating-out-model-and-views-and-controllers-in-different-projects seems like a duplice + I don't see real value in doing this, why do you want to separate those?